# import script in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

***Problem***

Hello to all, I don't understand why I cannot enter in an external file in WordPress through the script register:

if I try to load a simple `console.log('here')` inside the external file, simply I'm not able to launch it. It's like he didn't find the file.

maybe am I wrong something in the declarations?

***Code***

This is the register script

```
<?php

function wp_load_styles_on_init()
{
  if (!is_admin()){
    /* REGISTER SCRIPT */
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', array(), null, true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-js', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('slide-push-menu-js', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/slide-push-menu/js/menu.js', array('jquery','bootstrap-js'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('ie10-workaround-js', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/ie10-workaround/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js', array('jquery','bootstrap-js'), null, true);
    // wp_register_script('infinite-scroll', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll-helper.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('slick', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/slick-1.6.0/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('waypoints', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('visible-js', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/jquery.visible.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('functions-js', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/site-functions.js', array('jquery','bootstrap-js','ie10-workaround-js'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('home-function', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/home-function.js', array('jquery'),null, true);
    wp_localize_script('home-function', 'ajax_post_params', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
       wp_register_script('load-more', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/load-more.js', array('jquery'),null, true);
       wp_localize_script('load-more', 'ajax_single_params', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_register_script('fancybox', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('adv-function', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/adv-functions.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('top-banner-adv-functions', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/js/top-banner-adv-functions.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('final-banner-adv-functions', get_the_theme_uri() . '/js/final-banner-adv-functions.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('slide-push-menu-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('ie10-workaround-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints');
    wp_enqueue_script('visible-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('functions-js');

    if(is_front_page()){
      wp_enqueue_script('home-function');
      wp_enqueue_script('slick');
      wp_enqueue_script('adv-function');
      wp_enqueue_script('top-banner-adv-functions');
    }

    if(is_single() || is_category() || is_author()):
      // wp_enqueue_script('infinite-scroll');
      // wp_enqueue_script('single-function');
      wp_enqueue_script('load-more'); // and this one
      if(is_single() && get_query_var('post_type') != 'room'):
        wp_enqueue_script('adv-function');
        wp_enqueue_script('top-banner-adv-functions');
        wp_enqueue_script('final-banner-adv-functions');
      endif;
    endif;

    if(get_query_var('post_type') == 'room' || is_tax()):
      wp_enqueue_script('fancybox');
      wp_enqueue_script('adv-function');
      wp_enqueue_script('top-banner-adv-functions');
    endif;

    // $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    // if ( is_single() && 'video' ==  $queried_post_type):
    //   wp_dequeue_script('infinite-scroll');
    //   wp_dequeue_script('single-function');
    // endif;

    /* REGISTER STYLE */
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'ie10-workaround', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/js/ie10-workaround/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css', array('bootstrap'), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'slide-push-menu', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/js/slide-push-menu/css/menu.css', array('bootstrap'), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'fontello', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/css/fontello.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'slick', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/js/slick-1.6.0/slick.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '20180313', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'custom', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/css/custom.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'fancybox', get_the_vision_theme_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css', array(), '', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style('slide-push-menu');
    wp_enqueue_style('ie10-workaround');
    wp_enqueue_style('tv-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('ds-google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif',false);
    wp_enqueue_style('amiri-google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiri',false);
    wp_enqueue_style('fontello');
    wp_enqueue_style('slick');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom');

    if(get_query_var('post_type') == 'room'):
      wp_enqueue_style('fancybox');
    endif;

  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_load_styles_on_init' );
```

the interesting lines are the two unindented and this one down below

```
if(is_single() || is_category() || is_author()):
          // wp_enqueue_script('infinite-scroll');
          // wp_enqueue_script('single-function');
          wp_enqueue_script('load-more'); // and this one
```

Now, what I don't understand it's why the file load-more.js isn't even called.

Down below there is the tree of the files:

[image]

***Update***

i'm trying to go deep, and i lookin what the function `get_the_theme_uri()` actually does. Down below you will find the related code:

```
define('MY_WORDPRESS_FOLDER', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('MY_THEME_FOLDER', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
//define('MY_THEME_PATH', '/themes');
define('MY_THEME_PATH', '/' . substr(MY_THEME_FOLDER, stripos(MY_THEME_FOLDER, 'wp-content')));
function get_the_theme_uri()
{
    return MY_THEME_PATH;
}
```